# Chromedriver does not store the cookie when running Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I am writing E2E tests using Laravel Dusk and have encountered a problem that my session starts again on each request. Digging deaper I have found that Chromedriver is not storing any cookies at all, so the user does not have a session as he cant store a session key and on each request is considered being a new user.

What might be the possible reason of Chromedriver not storing a cookie? By the way I am running it on Gitlab.

Here is the test code:

```
public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee("add cluster")
                ->assertPathIs('/add-cluster')
                ->waitForText('Cluster list')
                ->pause(1000)
                ->click("[href='#addClusterModal']")
                ->waitForText("New cluster")
                ->whenAvailable('#addClusterModal', function ($modal) {
                    $modal->type("name", 'first cluster')
                        ->type('url', config('app.test-cluster-host'))
                        ->type('port', '9200')
                        ->press('Add')
                        ->pause(1000);
                })
                ->screenshot('add-cluster')
                ->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Simple summary of most important Cluster items');
        });
    }
```

Comment: how do you confirm chromedriver/chrome has an issue?

Comment: It is my guess, because there are no cookies set at all. And there is nothing I can configure with cookie setting. And the same cookies work locally when working and when testing locally.

Comment: Add the code of the test as it may help a bit

Comment: @TarunLalwani added. Please note, that it works when I run locally and only fails on the Gitlab CI.

Comment: `Digging deaper I have found that Chromedriver is not storing any cookies at all` - how did you find this?  While I'm sure the test you've shown uses cookies in your application back-end, we can't see that, so we have no way of knowing what is really happening.  Can you create an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the problem, eg sets a cookie and then tests it?  [Example](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/396).

Comment: @Don'tPanic when I put a method inside ->cookie('laravelsession') , it returns null

Comment: You see, the framework sets the cookies itself, so I am not sure how it is done. I have not touched anything on that part and also it did work locally.

Comment: A common answer when Laravel cannot store sessions is that it has not be installed properly, [specifically permissions are not set up on the directory where it stores session files](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation). Could that be the case here?  PS - `it returns null` - what does?  Be specific.  Edit your question, show your code!